# getting error BEA-001131 when connection is closing in weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, weblogic9.x

I have Installed weblogic 10.3.5 with jrocket 1.6.0_33. Oracle Fusion Middleware 11.1.1 on Windows Environment. On database side I have Oracle database 11gR2 RAC environment with Two instance on Linux Environment. I have created

```
GRIDLINK DataSource with NON-XA DRIVERS.                
NAME: test
JNDI: jdbc/testDS
```

NOTE: I have used SCAN IP for this DataSource configuration.

```
FAN ENABLED checked.
ONS HOST : scan-ip:6200
Not using "ONS Wallet".
```

The DataSource created successfully and Application also run but after few minutes or hours there some error accord in Managed Server console when  Connection for pool "test" is getting closed it through `error <JDBC> <BEA-001131> <Received an exception when closing a cached statement for the pool "test": SQLRecoverableException: Closed Coonection.>`
what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have any network device like a firewall between weblogic and your database ?

Comment: we are using Solaris Thin Client.